# Local Web Applications

Tags: local, web

Can someone provide me a direction or concept on how to set up a local web applications, for example, I currently use CUPS within Linux for printer setup and such. CUPS has a local web application by just changing the port number in the loopback address i.e.

```
127.0.0.1:631
```

And that takes you to the CUPS web interface. How is that set up? I'm sorry if this is a pretty easy question to answer, I just haven't really found a good answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to install Apache on your Linux box. Once you do that, you should be able to go to http://127.0.0.1 and see your home page. The page is usually stored in /srv/www but it really depends on the Linux distro that you use.

By the way, CUPS does not use Apache, which means that they implemented a mini web server for their web interface.